# get value of input inside table with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value of input which is inside `input` inside `td` but the one with specific `LogId` and set the value to inputs

that's my coede:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" style="cursor: pointer;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-detail"
                         onclick="openDetailModel('<%= searchtrans.getLogId()%>')">
<td class="">
<input type="hidden" logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="bRequest" value="<%=searchtrans.getBRequest()%>" >
<input type="hidden" logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="bResponse" value="<%= searchtrans.getBResponse() %>">
<input type="hidden" logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="sRequest" value="<%= searchtrans.getSRequest()%>" >
<input type="hidden" logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="sResponse" value="<%=searchtrans.getSResponse()%>">
 </td>
</tr>
```

and that is the JavaScript code I tried:

```
function openDetailModel(detailVal){
        var value = detailVal;
  
       var bRequest =  $("td #bRequest[logId ='" + value + "']").val();
       var bResponse = $("#bResponse[logId ='" + value + "']").val();
       var sRequest = $('#sRequest').val();
       var sResponse= $('#sResponse').val();

       
       document.getElementById('modelBRequest').value = bRequest;
       document.getElementById('modelBResponse').value = bResponse;
       document.getElementById('modelSRequest').value = sRequest;
       document.getElementById('modelSResponse').value = sResponse;
          
        }
```

I tried many approaches, but nothing worked.

Comment: `input` elements don't get a closing tag (`</input>`) and `logId` is an invalid attribute.

Comment: as i get the value and the id from a list coming from my controller, ok i will remove the closing tag , my fault

Comment: i tried to make `logId` as custom attribute to get the value of specific `logId`

Comment: HTML doesn't have custom attributes. You can't just make up your own. The closing thing are [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) - - that's what you should be using.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks man you are awesome !! you saved my day ! , that's what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot to @ScottMarcus after following his steps

that is my html after edit :

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" style="cursor: pointer;"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-detail"
                     onclick="openDetailModel('<%= searchtrans.getLogId()%>')">
<td class="">
<article  data-logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="bRequest" data-value="<%=searchtrans.getBRequest()%>" >
 <article  data-logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="bResponse" data-value="<%= searchtrans.getBResponse() %>">
<article  data-logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="sRequest" data-value="<%= searchtrans.getSRequest()%>" >
<article  data-logId="<%= searchtrans.getLogId() %>" id="sResponse" data-value="<%=searchtrans.getSResponse()%>">
</td>
</tr>
```

and my Js code :

```
function openDetailModel(detailVal){
        var value = detailVal;
        const input = document.querySelector("#bRequest[data-logId ='" + value + "']");

        const input2 = document.querySelector("#bResponse[data-logId ='" + value + "']");

        const input3 = document.querySelector("#sRequest[data-logId ='" + value + "']");

        const input4 = document.querySelector("#sResponse[data-logId ='" + value + "']");

       var bRequest =  input.dataset.value;
       var bResponse = input2.dataset.value;
       var sRequest = input3.dataset.value;
       var sResponse= input4.dataset.value;


       $('#modelRequest').val(bRequest);
       $('#modelBResponse').val(bResponse);
      $('#modelSRequest').val(sRequest);
       $('#modelSResponse').val(sResponse);

        }
```

Comment: I think that instead of `dataset.value` you meant `dataset.logId`. Also, ID's are unique, so your `querySelector()` arguments only need to be the element ID as in: `document.querySelector("#bRequest")`. No need to add the `[data-logId.....]` part since there is only one element with an ID of `bRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` to find the input inside clicked `tr`, see below code

```
function openDetailModel(detailVal){
        var value = detailVal;

       var bRequest =  $(this).find("td #bRequest[logId ='" + value + "']").val();
       var bResponse = $(this).find("#bResponse[logId ='" + value + "']").val();
       var sRequest = $(this).find('#sRequest').val();
       var sResponse= $(this).find('#sResponse').val();


       $('#modelBRequest').val(bRequest);
       $('#modelBResponse').val(bResponse);
       $('#modelSRequest').val(sRequest);
       $('#modelSResponse').val(sResponse);

        }
```

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it?

Comment: I am getting error in jsfiddle Uncaught ReferenceError: openDetailModel is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick ((index):69)

Comment: i opended the url the code works and it rendered the result

Comment: thanks man for your time , but i posted a solution that worked perfect for me after following @ScottMarcus  comments